# Solve for $x$ $\frac{1-3^x}{2^x-8} \le 0$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality

$\frac{1-3^x}{2^x-8} \le 0$

I tried:
$$\frac{1-3^x}{2^x-8} \le 0 \Leftrightarrow \frac{1^x}{2^x-8} - \frac{3^x}{2^x-8} \le 0 \Leftrightarrow -\frac{2^x}{2^x-8} \le 0 \Leftrightarrow ???$$

What do I do next?

Comment: No you need to consider negative numerator/positive denominator and vice versa

Comment: Two cases: numetator positive and denominator negative or numerator negative and denominator positive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For $x>3$, $2^{x}-8> 0$ and, hence, we have

$$
\frac{1-3^{x}}{2^{x}-8}\leq 0\iff 1-3^{x}\leq 0\iff1\leq 3^{x}\iff 0\leq x.
$$

For $x<3$, $2^{x}-8<0$ and, hence,  we have

$$
\frac{1-3^{x}}{2^{x}-8}\leq 0\iff 1-3^{x}\geq 0\iff 1\geq 3^{x}\iff x\leq 0.
$$

If you piece these inequalities together, you get your solution.